# Why there is a start (*) after Nodegroup:0 in MySQL cluster? What does it means?

Tags: mysql, mysql-cluster

I am new to MySQL and MySQL cluster setup. However going through several blogs and Web links I've finally able to manage the cluster up and running. I have 1 management, 1 SQL and 3 data nodes (currently without any replicated SQL or data nodes as I have set NoOfReplicas=1 in the config.ini file). After running ndb_mgm> show I can see there is a start just after the first data node, what does it means? I searched over google but didn't find any proper answer. Kindly help.

> ndb_mgm> show
>
> Cluster Configuration
>
> [ndbd(NDB)]     3 node(s)
>
> id=3    @10.10.10.3  (mysql-5.5.34 ndb-7.2.14, Nodegroup: 0, *)
>
> id=4    @10.10.10.4  (mysql-5.5.34 ndb-7.2.14, Nodegroup: 1)
>
> id=5    @10.10.10.5  (mysql-5.5.34 ndb-7.2.14, Nodegroup: 2)
>
> [ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
>
> id=1    @10.10.10.1  (mysql-5.5.34 ndb-7.2.14)
>
> [mysqld(API)]   1 node(s)
>
> id=6    @10.10.10.6  (mysql-5.5.34 ndb-7.2.14)

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shows which node is `master`. It is internal thing and probably the only visible effect of it is when exactly half of the nodes goes down. Then if one of the remaining nodes is master - cluster keeps working. If not - cluster aborts.

<s>http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-mysql-cluster.html#qandaitem-B-10-1-8</s>

**Updated link:**
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-mysql-cluster.html#faq-cluster-what-show-nodegroup-star

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. That totally answers my question :)